# Set child pid to 0 but output others

Tags: c

I read such a snippet of code from an instruction

```
#include "apue.h"

int globvar = 6; /* external variable in initialized data */
char buf[] = "a write to stdout\n";

int main(void)
{
    int var;
    pid_t pid; /* automatic variable on the stack */

    var = 88; if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1) != sizeof(buf) - 1)
        err_sys("write error");
    printf("before fork\n"); /* we don’t flush stdout */

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        err_sys("fork error");
    } else if (pid == 0) { /* child */
        globvar++;         /* modify variables */
        var++;
    } else {
        sleep(2); /* parent */
    }

    printf("pid = %ld, glob = %d, var = %d, bufsize = %lu\n", (long)getpid(), globvar, var, sizeof(buf));

    exit(0);
}
```

Run it and get outputs

```
$ ./a.out
a write to stdout
before fork
pid = 7310, glob = 7, var = 89, bufsize = 19 #child’s variables were changed 
pid = 7309, glob = 6, var = 88, bufsize = 19 #parent’s copy was not changed
```

I am confused about the child's pid

```
if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
```

the pid is set as 0, but in the output it's pid is 7310.

How could that happen?

does the pid here is just a number rather than a process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) returns 0 in the child process, but in the `printf` statement you are printing the pid using `getpid()` which is the actual pid of the child process.

If you had used `pid` in the `printf` statement instead of [`getpid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) you will see that it prints 0.